# Java self type recursive type parameters and inheritance error in javac

Tags: java, generics, javac, java-7, java-6

Why does this code not compile?

```
public class x
{
    private void test()
    {
        handle(new ThingA());
        handle(new ModifiedThingA());
    }

    private <T extends BaseThing<T>, X extends T> java.util.List<T> handle(X object)
    {
        return object.getList();
    }

    private static class BaseThing<T extends BaseThing<T>>
    {
        public java.util.List<T> getList()
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static class ThingA
        extends BaseThing<ThingA>
    {
    }

    private static class ModifiedThingA
        extends ThingA
    {
    }
}
```

Java 6 gives this this error in `handle(new ModifiedThingA());`:

```
x.java:6: <T,X>handle(X) in x cannot be applied to (x.ModifiedThingA)
            handle(new ModifiedThingA());
            ^
```

Java 7 does not even like `handle(new ThingA());`, this is the Java 7 output:

```
x.java:5: error: invalid inferred types for T; inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
            handle(new ThingA());
                  ^
    inferred: ThingA
    bound(s): CAP#1
  where T,X are type-variables:
    T extends BaseThing<T> declared in method <T,X>handle(X)
    X extends T declared in method <T,X>handle(X)
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends BaseThing<CAP#1> from capture of ?
x.java:6: error: invalid inferred types for T; inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
            handle(new ModifiedThingA());
                  ^
    inferred: ModifiedThingA
    bound(s): CAP#1
  where T,X are type-variables:
    T extends BaseThing<T> declared in method <T,X>handle(X)
    X extends T declared in method <T,X>handle(X)
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends BaseThing<CAP#1> from capture of ?
2 errors
```

It seems to me that `javac` is mistaking `ModifiedThingA` for a `BaseThing<ModifiedThingA>` when it is in fact a `BaseThing<ThingA>`. Is this my bug or `javac`'s?

Comment: What's the need for the `X` generic in the declaration of `handle`? Can't you just declare *object* to be of type `T`?

Comment: `T extends BaseThing<T>` would require `ModifiedThingA` to be a `BaseThing<ModifiedThingA>`. I want to accept anything that extends something like `ThingA`. ie. Anything that extends a valid implementation of `T extends BaseThing<T>`.

Comment: Inference of types gets a bit complicated. Fwiw, you can ditch the inference and specify the generic arguments explicitly. Replace the body of `test` with `this.<ThingA,ThingA>handle(new ThingA()); this.<ThingA,ModifiedThingA>handle(new ModifiedThingA());`

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar! Put that in an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline's solutions solves my example code, but not my real life code. Is `javac` getting the inference wrong? Should I file a bug report?

Comment: @Jesse javac is probably following [an interpretation of] the JLS. There have been bugs and specification ambiguities in the area. I couldn't tell you if the behaviour is consistent with the JLS or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`javac`'s behavior appears to be correct. Theoretically one type variable, `T`, would be sufficient. However, you introduced a second type variable, `X`, to help type inference along. The argument for `X` gets inferred first and then, based on the invocation context, the argument for `T` is inferred:

```
List<ThingA> a = handle(new ThingA());
List<ThingA> b = handle(new ModifiedThingA());
```

However, your invocation context does not put any bounds on the return type. Thus the compiler is [forced](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.8-120-A.5) to introduce a type variable (`CAP#1`) with the null type as lower bound. `T`'s argument will be inferred as `glb(BaseThing<CAP#1>) = BaseThing<CAP#1>`. Given its lower bound, `X` is not provably a subtype of `T`.

There are two or three ways out of this.

1. manually infer (okay if rarely necessary)
2. provide an "overload" with return type void (needs another name, urgh)
3. if the returned list is immutable or a defensive copy, you can disconnect the type argument `T` from its bounds argument

I prefer option 3:

```
private <T extends BaseThing<T>> List<T> handle(BaseThing<? extends T> object) {
    return new ArrayList<T>(object.getList());
    // or (using guava's ImmutableList)
    return ImmutableList.copyOf(object.getList());
}
```

Happy generics.

Comment: Thanks, option 3 is a nice solution, simply changing the method signature to `private <T extends BaseThing<T>> java.util.List<? extends T> handle(BaseThing<? extends T> object)` worked for my case, after looking at your answer.

Comment: Thanks for making the effort to provide such a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code compiles fine in javac 1.8.0_45 and Eclipse 4.1.1.

Probably the changes that where made to the type inference algorithm in Java 8 in order to compile lambda expressions in a nice way also solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in javac 1.7.0_09 and 1.7.0_11, which causes this problem.

Comment: Do you have a link to this bug?

Comment: @MattBall You can check the [Oracle Java Bug Database](https://search.oracle.com/search/search?search.timezone=-120&search_startnum=&search_endnum=&num=10&search_dupid=&exttimeout=false&actProfId=0&q=1.7.0_09+type+generics&group=bugs.sun.com&sw=t&search_p_main_operator=all&search_p_atname=&adn=&search_p_op=equals&search_p_val=&search_p_atname=&adn=&search_p_op=equals&search_p_val=)